# Как средствами openpyxl считать значение ячейки в том формате, как я вижу при открытом файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Сейчас я реализовываю функцию, которая на вход получает файл формата xlsx и парсит его в dictionary следующего вида:

```
parsed_excel_dict = {
 'sheet_name1': 'data':[[value_cell_A1, value_cell_A2,...], 
                       [value_cell_B1, value_cell_B2, ...]],
 'sheet_name2': ...
 }
```

При попытке чтения соответствующего поля у ячейки ожидаю увидеть строку в том виде, в котором она видна в открытом файле. Присутствуют следующие проблемы:

- считываемое значение типов datetime, float, int и других отображаются некорректно. Например: в ячейке файла вещественное число (9,00) возвращает 9. Хотя когда 9,01 - возвращаемое отображается корректно.
- Также не корректно отображаются денежные форматы и другие более сложные форматы, частные случаи float.

Кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой и нашел его решение прошу дать совет.
По просьбе @MaxU выкладываю пример файла, доступен по ссылке:
https://dropmefiles.com/lUf1E
На данном этапе получаю следующую структуру данных:

```
{'Test sheet': {'data': [[2, None, None, None, None, None, None], [5, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                         [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 9, 0, 0), None, None, None, None, None, None],
                         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 5, 19, 31, 21), None, None, None, None, None, None],
                         [datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 14, 0, 0), None, None, None, None, None, None],
                         [datetime.datetime(1901, 7, 8, 0, 0), None, None, None, None, None, None],
                         [45, None, None, None, None, None, None], [88787, None, None, None, None, None, None],
                         [45456, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, 2, None, None, None, None, None]],
                'count': 7}}
```

Comment: Pandas обычно правильно парусит Excel файлы

Comment: В том виде в котором видите в файле попробуйте в `load_workbook` указывать `data_only=True`.

Comment: Параметр data_only  подгружает вычисленные значения в ячейках: если в ячейке формула - возвращает вычисленное значение. Я имею в виду проблему оно не решило.

Comment: @MaxU хорошая идея и возможно она решит мою проблему, но нужно использовать именно openpyxl.

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян, можете выложить пример Excel файла на какой-нибудь файлообменник?